# jQuery: performing operations on an array of objects?

Tags: jquery

I have 4 jQuery objects (i.e. things constructed via `$("ObjectID")`), and I would like to perform the same operation to all of them, in an elegant fashion. I would have thought that something like these would work, but it doesn't seem to:

```
$([obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]).change(function() { otherObj.show(); });
$([obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Is there a good syntax for this? It seems like a somewhat blinding oversight. Currently the best I'm seeing is

```
$([obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]).each(
    function() { this.change(function() { otherObj.show(); }));
```

Comment: That top syntax should be working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you have:

```
var obj1 = $("...");
var obj2 = $("...");
var obj3 = $("...");
var obj4 = $("...");
```

?

If so, you can turn them into a single set:

```
var complete = obj1.add(obj2).add(obj3).add(obj4);
```

and then just use the final set to:

```
complete.change(function() {
  otherObj.show();
}).attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: According to http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add the .add() function isn't limited to one new element at a time

Comment: This is pure genius. You saved me so much time.

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching a class to the objects when you create them and doing

```
$(".class")
    .change(function(){otherObj.show();})
    .attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution, but the answer I accepted is the one that will work in all circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for ids:

```
$("#obj1,#obj2,#obj3,#obj4")
```

It will also work for any selector. You can combine anything in a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [each](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) command is certainly one way of tackling it, however there are other approaches.

You can [peel away the jQuery object to get an array](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/peeling-away-the-jquery-wrapper-and-finding-an-array), perform whatever you need to do on the array and then wrap it back into a jQuery object.

There are also a number of [plugins with array methods and enumurables](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/implementing-prototypes-array-methods-in-jquery) that allow you to manipulate arrays and jQuery objects.